# Can we process parquet file through external table in Netezza

Tags: netezza

We have a requirement to process data from azure to Netezza. We were able to achieve it through external table and did a poc where we loaded csv/text files into Netezza.

We would like to know if it's possible to load parquet file format into Netezza. We went through IBM documents and found a link where it stated use **Format** **"Parquet"** option for processing but we were unable to execute it. The other document from IBM stated that only allowed formats are **"text"** and **"fixed"** .

Can someone share your knowledge on this?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is recently released and only available in the latest version of Netezza.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of the new released support for this use case - https://medium.com/@MikeDeRoy/using-netezza-performance-server-on-cloud-as-a-data-lakehouse-9274252de9d8

Comment: Hi, so does this only work on the Netezza cloud version? . What we have is on-prem Netezza system so would like to confirm the same.